# blower motor wiring

Tags: wiring, blower

hoping someone can help me verify my wiring to a AC blower motor. I think I have it wired correctly, I followed pics I took before I swapped out the motor. According to the diagram on the motor, black is high, red low and purple to line. Low was not previously used, nor is it now. When I turn the ac on the outside compressor comes on but the blower mortor does not. Theres no reset switch that I could see and I think I have the wiring correct. Also I replaced the capacitor and I just plugged the two brown wires to it, I'm using polarity is not important and I can just plug the brown wires in any order to the capacitor, btw it's the same capacitor.

Thanks in advance for taking the time to help me.

P
[image: wiring]

Comment: Are you sure it was the motor that was dead to begin with, not the capacitor?

Comment: So it was actually the capacitor but I had bought the blower motor, it's the same direct replacement. Now I have a new capacitor and motor, but when I turn on the ac only the outside unit comes on. Breaker for blower is on. I will need to got back in the attic but was wondering if someone noticed any issues with the wiring.

Comment: It sounds like you wired it right are you sure that the contactor was not the problem?

Answer (score 2):

Today I went into the hot attic looked at the wiring and the posted wiring diagram and noticed the black wire to the relay switch was on 2 when it should of been on terminal 1. Once I made that change it started working. I will post a picture below.[image]

Comment: It's always the simple things that get you. At least you had a before pic to compare to